# Codeigniter Model returning empty data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with my model. It's returning empty data.

Here is the controller.

```
public function getReport() {        
  $data = array();
  
  $id = $this->input->post('id');

  $this->auth->setId($id);

  $data['instant_main']=$this->auth->getReportData();
              
  $this->load->view('auth/report-item', $data);
}
```

and this is my Model

```
class Auth_model extends CI_Model {
    // Declaration of a variables
    private $_id;

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->_id = $id;
    }

    function getReportData()
    {
     

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('inbound_main');
        $this->db->join('inbound_item', 'inbound_main.id = inbound_item.report_id');
        $this->db->where('inbound_item.report_id', $this->_id);
        
        $query = $this->db->get();
        
        return $query->result();
    }

}
```

If I have removed the **WHERE** condition from the query, everything was fine.

Comment: `echo $this->db->get_compiled_select()` and see what do you get, copy the generated query and run directly on database

Comment: did you check if $id has a value (in your controller)?

Answer (score 0):

Your $this_id is empty..

You have folow the code like this

Controller
$data['instant_main']=$this->auth->getReportData($id);

Model
function getReportData($id)
{

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('inbound_main');
    $this->db->join('inbound_item', 'inbound_main.id = inbound_item.report_id');
    $this->db->where('inbound_item.report_id', $id);
    
    $query = $this->db->get();
    
    return $query->result();
}
```